# Import Drupal 6 content types into Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, import, upgrade, cck, drupal-7

What happened to `/admin/content/types/import` in D7?
Can you still import a content type (not the actual data) in D7? In D6 you could at /admin/content/types/import. Has this feature just moved somewhere else?

I want to export some nodes from a D6 site to D7 (not the entire site) with [drupal.org/project/node_export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export). However the content type does not exist on my new D7 site.

In general, what is the best way to upgrade some CCK data from a D6 site to D7 without doing a full upgrade (they are different sites).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the ability to define new fields is in built in Drupal 7's admin UI, a number of D6 features still remain in the contrib 'CCK' project, including code to upgrade old fields from contrib modules to the D7 field structure. You'll need to grab the [latest version of CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) and use its "content migrate" module, and also keep a close on [these three](http://drupal.org/node/781088) [in-progress](http://drupal.org/node/1018580) [issues](http://drupal.org/node/1018550). The field migration code for many D6 field types isn't completed, and before flipping the switch on a production site you'll want to make sure that the upgrade path works smoothly.

While the full D7 upgrade isn't what you're gunning for, those issues are the ones that will need to be resolved for D6 field structures (what you'd get from something like content_export and content_import) to be pulled into D7 successfully.

(By request, [a restored link to the D6 to D7 upgrade flowchart](http://www.lullabot.com/sites/lullabot.com/files/D7UpgradeChart.png) -- the original version from the first post was redone by an actual designer for a [D7 Upgrade podcast](http://www.lullabot.com/podcasts/podcast-90-drupal-7-are-you-ready), and now looks less like a tangle of snakes!)

Comment: Thanks for the links and flowchart. This is helpful. BTW, I  caught the video http://drupalize.me/videos/overview-drupal-7, which I believe you are part of, and it was very good.

Comment: Can you restore the flowchart image you provided or add a link to the comments please. Though it doesn't deal directly with this question, I do have another site which will go the full D6 >> D7 upgrade path and would like another look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to import content you can look in to this module: http://drupal.org/project/defaultcontent

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be not possible ATM since CCK moved into core.

You might have a read at the [Drupal sites](http://drupal.org/node/781088) that is discussing this and writing a module/workarounds/...

Comment: it not being possible ATM is what I am fearing. I know that `/admin/structure/content_migrate` works pretty well if you are upgrading a site. Since this site did not contain the legacy CCK types, there is no field definitions to migrate at the moment.  But also at a cursory glance notice that my D6 db has `content_*` tables while D7 does not. I wonder if adding these manually to my D7 database would be enough for them to magically be migrated...will keep you posted.

Comment: Nope...that was a naive idea from me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the features module, you can import the content type or other pieces (such as taxonomy, ...). I have successfully imported the content types, but now I'm stuck as to how to import the content. Ive been pointed towards feeds and am trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following helping module for drupal migration

- [migrate](https://drupal.org/project/migrate)
- [backup_migrate](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate)
- [migrate_extras](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_extras)

Also read helping content links:

- [Upgrading Drupal core](https://drupal.org/documentation/upgrade)
- [Migrate Contents from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 Using Migrate 2](http://miss-hana.com/migrate-contents-from-drupal-6-to-drupal-7-using-migrate-2/)
- [Converting 6.x modules to 7.x](https://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7)
- [Upgrading 6.x themes to 7.x](https://drupal.org/update/themes/6/7)

Answer (score 0):

Now you can add new content types under Structure -> Content Types

> admin/structure/types

Though there is no option to "import", you will be able to add them from there. But I guess you won't have too much content types.

Comment: I am aware that you can add a new content type at that location, however it would be extra work and prone to failure. If the database schema or field names changed between versions of d6 and d7, which I am guessing have, this would not work well with node_export import.

Answer (score 0):

Node export maintainer here - I wouldn't even bother trying this.  I'm really stuck on converting D6 nodes to D7, and how to convert CCK and taxonomy to the D7 Fields, and the lack of content type import makes it even more difficult.  Quite disappointing.  If anyone can lend a hand please seek out the node_export issue queue.

Answer (score 0):

To import content you can use feeds or migrate module

Comment: @E Ismail the question I asked is not how to import content from outside sources but how to import Drupal specific content types into Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a combination of Features (on D6) and Bundle Copy (on D7). I wrote a script that can convert a Features module content types into Bundle Copy's import format.

A more complete set of instructions is here: https://thoughtfuldragon.com/converting-drupal-6-cck-content-types-into-drupal-7-entity-bundles/